# Overload binary operator to unary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to overload binary operator to make it unary in Python?

E.g. I want `|` take only one positional argument.

Tried such code:

```
def __or__(self):
    return self.a + self.b
```

(Same with `__ror__`)

And got this:

`|foo` --- *SyntaxError: invalid syntax*

`foo|` --- *SyntaxError: invalid syntax*

`foo | bar` --- *TypeError: `__or__()` takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given*

Or maybe I should take `None` as an argument somehow to make `None` parse as one of positional arguments?

Comment: That's impossible... That wouldn't match proper python syntax.

Comment: Can you have a random value in the other side, like say 0 or "" and just ignore such value?

Comment: @Zaid Al Shattle Unfortunatly, not. According to the task, I have to call `abs` by typing `|foo|`. So, I decided to overload _or_ and _ror_. As I undarstand, python interpretter going to parse that construction as bitwise operators anyway and trow the exception, so there is no way to make it done, right?

Comment: Nothing I can think off from the top of my head, but it doesn't seem very likely, especially if its not a string you are manipulating